# nao.rviz config file not found in the repo

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm following the tutorial on http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started and in the Step 1.1. where I'm supposed to select a nao.rviz

```
src/nao_robot/nao_description/config/nao.rviz
```

I cannot find in the specified directory and as a result not able to load nao onto rviz.

You quick response would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284122/nao.rviz-config-file-not-found-in-the-repo./) by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial seems outdated as it starts with "Note: WARNING: This tutorial may be outdated and specific to the Nao ROS packages v0.1.". Maybe there is another tutorial that is more recent/up-to-date?

Looking at the `nao_robot` repository, there are 2 RViz config files:

- `urdf.rviz` file in `src/nao_robot/nao_description/config/urdf.rviz` that displays the robot model and it's transforms
- `nao_full.rviz` at [nao_bringup/config/nao_full.rviz](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_robot/blob/master/nao_bringup/config/nao_full.rviz). It seems to display the sensor data as well and not only the model of the robot.

As the screenshot in the tutorial shows camera images and sonar data, I think you want to use the second one.
Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on 2018-03-05**:
Thanks for your reply. I already tried the config file you specified. As soon as I select this config file rviz crashes with this error:

[ERROR] [1520245896.720572456]: Error getting latest time from frame 'base_footprint' to frame 'base_footprint':  (Error code: 1)

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-03-06**:
@ravit: your comment doesnt contain the error message. Your question doesnt give enough information. Please update your question with the set of commmands you ran as well as any meaningful information to help us help you. See [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do)

**Comment by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on 2018-03-06**:
Thanks and sorry about that, I'm rather new to this forum.

When I select nao_full.rviz at nao_bringup/config/nao_full.rviz -- rviz crashes with the following message

[ERROR] [1520330262.218568929]: Error getting latest time from frame 'base_footprint' to frame 'base_footprint':  (Error code:1)

**Comment by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on 2018-03-06**:
When I select urdf.rviz file in src/nao_robot/nao_description/config/urdf.rviz -
rviz snapshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bie6wse7sskcau/rviz_error_urdf_rviz_config.png?dl=0
Under 'RobotModel'>>'Status Error">>'URDF' - Parameter [robot_description] does not exist, and was not found by searchParam()

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-03-09**:
This still doesn't give use the commands you ran before starting RViz. Did you run any launchfile from nao_bringup before starting RViz (cf 1.0 of tutorial) ?
robot description is set in nao_description/upload_nao.launch, that is launched automatically when you start nao_bringup/nao_full_py.launch